# Highstocks: Move Renderer elements along with navigator/ Draw Trendlines

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

Is it possible to move any elements added using

```
chart.renderer
```

as we update the range or the navigator handles?

There is a square in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ne7QV/). Can we shift its position as we update the navigator?

Or can you point me to the function in the source code that can help?

Thanks

**Update**: i want to draw trendlines/ fibonnacci retracements etc. based on user events. Currently, i draw & drag the lines using chart.renderer until the mouseup event, calculate the x,y values of the end points, delete the rendered lines & then add new series which visually imitate those rendered lines. This is surely not the best solution. The issue is how to remember the position of the user selection & show/scale the same only when those lines are in the visible range.

So i am wondering if we could directly use some internal "scaling" function that calculates the visible points of the series based on the current extremes.

Comment: Did you ever get an idea of how to automatically scale?

Answer (score 0):

Rendered object's position is basend on pixels, so when you use navigator, pixels "are the same" so object stay in the same position. But you can catch navigator "sliding" by [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes) and [aftersetExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) functions and then move element by translate().

Simple example of using translate():

```
obj.translate(120,20);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ne7QV/1/

Only what you need is common both elements, according to your expectations.

Comment: thank you for the reply. i have updated the question with more details.